# Pandas - How to print specific elements of a dataframe when a column is True

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Imagine we have the following dataframe:

```
data={'Process_ID':['12345-98', '23547-75', '85763-99','44231-56','78456-00','53218-87'],
     'Date': ['2021-06-30','2022-08-10','2021-06-15','2023-10-02','2024-04-03','2021-06-25'],
     'Check': ['True','False','False','True','True','False']}

df=pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

The output is the following:

```
 Process_ID        Date  Check
0   12345-98  2021-06-30   True
1   23547-75  2022-08-10  False
2   85763-99  2021-06-15  False
3   44231-56  2023-10-02   True
4   78456-00  2024-04-03   True
5   53218-87  2021-06-25  False
```

How can I print the process_IDs and the dates only for the rows where df['check']=="True"?

I tried to do something like this, but it did not work:

```
def get_true(dataframe):
    
    if dataframe['new']=='True':
        
        print(f"""Process_ID: {dataframe['Process_ID']} \n
                  Due Date: {dataframe['Date']}""")

get_true(df)
```

I got the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I would like the result to be a string like this:

```
Process_ID: xxxxx-xx
Due Date: dd/mm/yyyy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df['Check']=df['Check'].map({'True':True,'False':False})
#OR
df['Check']=pd.eval(df['Check'])
```

Finally:

```
out=df.loc[df['Check'],['Process_ID','Date']]
#OR if you want to print info then:
print(df.loc[df['Check'],['Process_ID','Date']])
```

output of `out`:

```
    Process_ID  Date
0   12345-98    2021-06-30
3   44231-56    2023-10-02
4   78456-00    2024-04-03
```

**Update:**

use a custom function:

```
def printfunc():
    df['Check']=pd.eval(df['Check'].astype(str).str.title())
    out=df.loc[df['Check'],['Process_ID','Date']].T
    for x in out:
        print('Process ID:',out[x].values[0],'\nDue Date:',out[x].values[1],'\n')

printfunc()
```

output of above code:

```
Process ID: 12345-98 
Due Date: 2021-06-30 

Process ID: 44231-56 
Due Date: 2023-10-02 

Process ID: 78456-00 
Due Date: 2024-04-03
```

**Note:** you can skip this line inside function `df['Check']=pd.eval(df['Check'].astype(str).str.title())` if you already run this code `df['Check']=pd.eval(df['Check'])`

**OR**

use `agg()` and `rename()`:

```
df.loc[df['Check'],['Process_ID','Date']].rename(columns={'Date':'Due Date'}).agg(','.join)
```

output of above code:

```
Process_ID          12345-98,44231-56,78456-00
Due Date      2021-06-30,2023-10-02,2024-04-03
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. However, I don't need to generate another dataframe or a Series. I need to print the information like this: "Process_ID": {df['Process_ID']} \n Due Date: {df['Date]}". I am going to automate an email with this information afterwards. I updated the post to make it clearer.

Comment: @ Anurag Dabas Thank you so much! I am trying to include the result of this printfunc() inside a f'string, but the value is coming out as 'None'. Do you know why?

Comment: @programmer987 between this function is just printing the values it's not returning anything so that's the reason that you are getting `'None'` if you try to use something like `f"{printfunc()}"`

Comment: I tried this, but it is not working. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
df.Check.replace({'True': True, 'False': False}, inplace=True)
index_have_check_true = df[df.Check].index.tolist()
def fun(i):
    print("\nProcess_ID : ", df['Process_ID'][i], "\nDue Date : ", df['Date'][i],"\n")
for i in index_have_check_true:
    fun(i)

def fun(i):
    print("\nProcess_ID : ", df['Process_ID'][i], "\nDue Date : ", df['Date'][i],"\n")
for i in index_have_check_true:
    fun(i)

Process_ID :  12345-98 
Due Date :  2021-06-30 


Process_ID :  44231-56 
Due Date :  2023-10-02 


Process_ID :  78456-00 
Due Date :  2024-04-03
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.Check.replace({'True': True, 'False': False}, inplace=True)
index_have_check_true = df[df.Check].index.tolist()
new_df = df.iloc[ index_have_check_true , : ]
new_df.head()
    Process_ID  Date    Check
0   12345-98    2021-06-30  True
1   23547-75    2022-08-10  False
2   85763-99    2021-06-15  False
3   44231-56    2023-10-02  True
4   78456-00    2024-04-03  True

new_df[['Process_ID','Date']]
    Process_ID  Date
0   12345-98    2021-06-30
3   44231-56    2023-10-02
4   78456-00    2024-04-03

for index, row in new_df.iterrows():
    print("\nProcess_ID : ", new_df['Process_ID'][index], "\nDue Date : ", new_df['Date'][index],"\n")
    
Process_ID :  12345-98 
Due Date :  2021-06-30 


Process_ID :  44231-56 
Due Date :  2023-10-02 


Process_ID :  78456-00 
Due Date :  2024-04-03
```

Comment: iterating over a dataframe in a for loop is almost always a bad idea.. extract it to a function and apply that function